# Regular Expression php for removing some content in double brackets

Tags: php

I want to remove the pattern from the expression in php

```
$string="[हो_VAUX, अस_VAUX] :   837";
```

I want to get the pattern `हो,अस` as answer.
So, I did this

```
$str=preg_replace('/\[ _A-Z/', '', $string);//removes backspace characters

$str=strstr($str, "_", true); //remnoves all the characters of the right to _.
```

I want to get  `हो,अस`. Please help me understand this. `हो,अस`

Answer (score 1):

Why not use this?

```
$str=preg_replace('/\w|\[|\]|:|\s/', '', $string);
```

outputs

```
हो,अस
```

Explanation

```
\w = 0-9a-zA-Z_ 
| = or
\[ = [
| = or
\] = ]
| = or
: = :
| = or
\s = ' '
```

i even minimized it a bit more.

And if you really want to get fancy

```
 $str = preg_replace("/^.*?(हो).*?(अस).*?$/", "\1,\2",$string);
```

Comment: +1 This is probably the most reliable way to do it OP.

Answer (score 0):

Look this will get the job done but it is in no way the most efficient way of doing this:

```
$string="[हो_VAUX, अस_VAUX] :   837";
$str=preg_replace('/[a-zA-Z0-9]+/', '', $string);//removes backspace characters
$str = str_replace(array(':', '_', ']', '[', ' '), '', $str);

echo $str;
```

Which gives you:

```
हो,अस
```

[**`Example`**](https://eval.in/169346)

---

Explanation:

- The first replace - `preg_replace()` removes all alphanumeric caracters
- The second replace - `str_replace()` removes the supplied array of unwanted characters from the string.

Answer (score 0):

Try to this single Line,

```
$testString = "[हो_VAUX, अस_VAUX] :   837";
echo preg_replace("/[A-Z0-9\]\[_:\s]/", "", $testString);
```

Comment: forgot the space \s, there is a space still in the output

Answer (score 0):

If simply removing all the alpha-numeric and a few select symbolic characters gets your answer, the following code will do the work:

```
$answer = preg_replace('/\\w|[][ :]/', '', $string);
//                               ^- add more symbols here
```

Comment: Thank You Guys.Could you please help me which book is good to understand php regular expressions.